# Including a grammar with CMU pocketsphinx gstreamer

Tags: python, grammar, gstreamer, cmusphinx

I have been looking into CMU pocketsphinx for voice recognition. Ideally I want to be able to recognize sentence structures along the line of "Please pick up " where  is a large list of objects (~200), using live audio as input. Initially I had a great deal of difficulty installing pocketsphinx on Ubunutu, eventually I was able to get it working using gstreamer. Now that I have it working, I am working on improving the accuracy. I would like to include a jsgf grammar but am unable to find any instructions or examples of code, and am currently at a loss.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use JSGF in gstreamer right now, though it would be a trivial change of the plugin. But you can use grammars in FSG format. You can construct the grammar in FSG format yourself or convert the grammar from JSGF format to FSG format:

```
sphinx_jsgf2fsg -jsgf grammar.jsgf -fsg grammar.fsg
```

To use grammar in fsg format, use "fsg" property of the plugin just like you are using "lm" property instead  of:

```
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filter), "lm", MODELDIR "/lm/en/turtle.DMP", NULL);
```

You set FSG property to FSG file:

```
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filter), "fsg", 
         "pocketsphinx/test/data/goforward.fsg", NULL);
```

You can do the same in python::

```
    asr.set_property("fsg", "pocketsphinx/test/data/goforward.fsg")
```

Comment: Hi, Just wanted to follow up on this. Thank you for the help. So after I attempted to include the fsg file, the program kept giving a segmentation fault. It took a while to figure out, but it turns out you have to set the dict, lm, and fsg properties before         `asr.set_property('configured', True)` in order for it not to fault. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: If you meet a segmentation fault you are welcome to report it in CMUSphinx bug tracking system. Don't mind to provide more details about the reasons.

Comment: @Niklay Shmyrev Do you know where I could find the documentation for pocketsphinx in python? I have been having trouble locating it and was hoping you could help.

Comment: Is there any place where I can read about the FSG format? It appears that the developers completely ommited any form of documentation. It's appalling

Comment: Update: Simply use sphinx_jsgf2fsg to convert the grammar. It is present in the sphinxbase-utils package.